# Accessing models by variable model name in django

Tags: python, django

I have two identical models, let's say X and Y in django like this:

```
class X(models.Model):
    con = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    a = models.ForeignField("FOO")

class Y(models.Model):
    con = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    b = models.ForeignField("BAR")
```

To access an object of these models, I have to use the following code:

```
models.X.objects.get(
    con = "something",
    a = xy
)

models.Y.objects.get(
    con = "something",
    b = yx
)
```

Is there a way to set the model name as variable such as `model_name = X` and then use this code to access the objects:

```
models.model_name.objects.get(**my_dict)
```

where

```
my_dict = {"con":"something", "a":xy}
```

Comment: If you have two identical models may be something wrong with your database schema, and you should move your model name into tables field.

Comment: The app requires two models because I need two different foreign keys coupled with other fields which are similar but may contain different values.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could do something like this:

```
getattr(models, model_name).objects.get(**my_dict)
```

It allows you to access the attributes of `models` via strings or variables.

Comment: so basically, what I should do is `getattr(models, X).objects.get(**my_dict)`?

Comment: No, `X` should be written as string. So you write `getattr(models, 'X').objects.get(**my_dict)`

Answer (score 3):

You certainly can:

```
setattr(models, 'model_name', models.X)
```

This will set the `model_name` attribute to models.X (or models.Y), which will make your call `models.model_name.objects.get(**my_dict)` succeed.

Alternatively, you could save the model you want to use in a variable before doing your work and use that from then on:

```
model_name = models.X
model_name.objects.get(**my_dict)
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way that I used is to use `django.apps`:

```
from django.apps import apps
model_name = 'X' # or 'Y'
my_dict = {"con":"something", "a":xy} # as suggested in the problem

model_class = apps.get_model(
  app_label='name_of_app_where_model_is_defined', 
  model_name=model_name
)
model_class.objects.get(**my_dict)
```